# Question about "embedding_v1" variable in the google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am a researcher interested in utilizing the "embedding_v1" variable from the "patents-public-data:google_patents_research.publications" dataset for my study, where I aim to assess the similarity between two patents. I seek additional information about the generation process of the "embedding_v1" variable, including details regarding the machine learning model employed, the potential impact of different languages on variable generation, and any other pertinent aspects. Further information on the "embedding_v1" variable would greatly benefit my research. Thank you for your assistance!

i want to know more information about the vairable.Thank you!